# Flow Trigger when Field is changed from Certain Value

Tags: visual-workflow, process-builder, workflow, field-update, updaterecord

This has been tricking me up all day and I would love some assistance. I have a flow that I need to update field1 when field2 is updated. The tricky part is I only want this to happen when field2 is a certain value before it is changed. I cannot seem to get the PriorValue and IsChanged Functions to operate properly together nor can I find an effective way to do this in flow or process builder.

Comment: what do you currently have? Screenshots of any criteria in your flow would be helpful to share in an [edit].

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunatly, Flows don't have yet available the Record__Prior value on the start element. So, for you to accomplish this you need to do this in two separate moments:

1. START: Verify that field2 has been changed
2. DECISION: Verify that {!$Record__Prior.field2} had the prior value that verifies the criteria

I just tested this and it's working well for me.

Comment: Thanks! This worked